# What does "change" "repair" or "remove" mean in the blender installer?

Tags: windows, installation

When I try to install blender, it says *change, repair, or remove*. I tried clicking change and repair, and install after that but it does nothing. When I delete it and try again the same thing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are using a Windows installer. If that is so, Change, Repair, Remove are the options the installer is giving you. Remove would be un-installation, Repair would be like a re-installation. It should be noted that there is no reason to install Blender on your system, and in fact it is desirable not to. Instead download the compressed archive of Blender for your OS and you can drop the program into your root project directory. This way you can keep whatever version of Blender you are using for each project along with addons/settings on a per project basis and it will be fully portable to other computers. Helps ensure you maintain project compatibility and prevents you from ending up with a dozen Blender installs on your system as each version comes out. Especially true if you ever use developer builds or branches.

Answer (score 0):

That dialogue is standard in most windows installers.
Having those options (instead of just install) means you already have a version of blender installed on your system.

Being thus you have the options to:

- "change" that installation (used in some programs to install optional components). For example if you did not install the blender player, you could "change" your installation and add it.
- "repair" the installer will *attempt* to overwrite any damaged files.
- "remove" simply remove, or uninstall the program.

---

At this point you *should* have a working blender installed on your system. If not, then I would recommend you uninstall blender (the "remove" option), either try installing it again, or better yet use the [zip archive](https://www.blender.org/download/Blender2.79/blender-2.79b-windows64.zip/).